# website search not working - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having trouble fixing the search feature on my site.

I get an error that says "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in /wp-content/themes/freetheme/content-excerpt.php on line 124**"

I have looked for line 24 and found this function

```
        if (!empty($dt = theme_get_date())) {
            ?>
            <div class="date_posted_block">
                <span class="date_posted">
                    <?php echo wp_kses_data($dt); ?>
                </span>
            </div>
```

Comment: It says line 124, not 24

Comment: The error says line *1*24 and you say you posted line 24.  Is it a typo in the question or did you get the wrong line?

Comment: sorry, it is a type in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have for the right line.  The assignment syntax inside the `empty()` appears not to be valid.

I tested as follows:

```
function foo() {}
if( empty( $bar = foo() ) ) { 
   echo "empty"; 
} else { 
   echo "not empty"; 
}
```

and got the same error.  What this means is you need to change

```
if (!empty($dt = theme_get_date())) {
```

to

```
$dt = theme_get_date();
if (!empty($dt)) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
This is what I get after amending the code as you suggested: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: Sorry. Missed The semi-colon after the first line. Will edit the answer